# ng-class messing with the order of classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have some very simple Angular code which looks like this...

```
<div ng-repeat="message in data.messages" ng-class="'conversationCard-' + 
message.type"></div>
```

It works, but the resulting output looks like this....

```
<div ng-repeat="message in data.messages" ng-class="'conversationCard-' + 
message.type" class="ng-scope conversationCard-phone"></div>
```

The problem is that my class now starts with ng-scope which is breaking my css selector which looks like this..

```
[class^="conversationCard"]
```

Is there any way of getting angular to remove the ng-scope, or at the very least put it at te end of the class declarations?

Comment: Did you consider changing your css selector for this: [class*="conversationCard"] instead?

Comment: I'd also like to second Josep's suggestion. Can you please explain the use case of looking for class using the attribute sellector + needing it to be first?

Comment: or [class^="ng-scope conversationCard"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter if you wanted to access that class via css:

```
div.conversationCard-phone{
    //css stuff
}
```

I'm not sure why you're using the ability to specify attributes in your css for classes, the method I've described is the common way of doing it. Can you perhaps elaborate on why you're using the attribute selector?

**Edit**

Change your html to

```
<div ng-repeat="message in data.messages" ng-class="message.type" class="conversationCard"></div>
```

So that processed it becomes

```
<div ng-repeat="message in data.messages" ng-class="message.type" class="ng-scope conversationCard phone"></div>
```

So in your css you can do

```
div.conversationCard{
    //css stuff
}
```

And if you want to isolate the phone one:

```
div.conversationCard.phone{
    //css stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the attribute selector to match any class which starts with the string "conversationCard-". Possible endings include -phone -email -meeting -note etc. so the attribute selector would allow me to select any combination. unfortunately the class attribute has to start with that string, not "ng-scope", hence the selector is not matching anything.

Comment: I edited my answer to do what you're asking, without using the attribute selector.

Comment: Mathew, it seem using two classes is the only way to do it, which is a shame because it's not as neat but it seems there's no way of stopping Angular from changing the order of classes in the attribute.

Answer (score -1):

How about void using ng-class, just use class like this

```
<div ng-repeat="message in data.messages" class="conversationCard-{{message.type}}"></div>
```

Comment: ng-class serves a very important purpose, ensuring that angular has done its calculations for the class before rendering happens, so the page doesn't flicker into a different state. Skipping ng-class is not recommended.

Comment: I think you can use it with ngCloak and avoid the page flick.